# window.rewardful is not a function when integrating Rewardful into Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, affiliate

I have inserted the code snippets given by [rewardful](https://www.rewardful.com/) into my next.js _document.js file in order to have the required code on every page, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function func1(w,r) {
      w._rwq=r;w[r]=w[r]||function(){(w[r].q=w[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}
    }
    func1(window,'rewardful');
  }, []);
```

And this is my head tag. APIKEY replaces the API key I have in the code:

```
<Head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"></link>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin></link>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<Script async src='https://r.wdfl.co/rw.js' data-rewardful='APIKEY'></Script>
</Head>
```

I am using Stripe elements as a checkout, and when I try to call `window.rewardful('convert', { email: email });`, or `rewardful('convert', { email: email });`, I am told that `window.rewardful is not a function` and `rewardful is not defined` respectively.

It is being called when `paymentIntent.status` is `succeeded`.

Comment: Hey Rob, I work for Rewardful. What's your website/app? I'll get one of the devs to take a look, and then provide a response here for others to see.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here is the deployment with the rewardful integration: https://wifistacks-git-main-robtherobot12.vercel.app/

Comment: hey Rob, sorry for the delay coming back here, we don't monitor SO that often. The support team said that they'll need more information to help and doing so on here might take a bit too much back and forth. Can you please reach out to support and then once we figure out the issue you can post the answer here after the fact.

Comment: I managed to sort the issue with your team a few days after I posted that comment, I'll post a solution soon

Comment: Hello rob, were you able to make it work with your react app? My team has been struggling with this as well.

@EmmetGibney it could be very helpful if your team's docs addressed this. Because the videos show a very quick integration, but so far, this has been non-trivial in React.

Comment: Hello @AndyBarr, check the answer I've posted, this is what I did. My apologies for not posting when I did find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to **not** to use `useEffect()` and instead load required content using Next.js `<Script />` tags with `strategy` set to `before-interactive`. If you don't load before interactive it won't work.

`_document.js`:

```html
<body>
    ...
    <Script id="rewardful_func" strategy="beforeInteractive"> 
    {`(function(w,r){w._rwq=r;w[r]=w[r]||function(){(w[r].q=w[r].q|| 
    []).push(arguments)}})(window,'rewardful');`
    } </Script>

    <Script id="rewardful_api" 
    strategy="beforeInteractive" 
    src="https://r.wdfl.co/rw.js" 
    data-rewardful="YOUR_REWARDFUL_CODE" >
    </Script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob! This is much appreciated and helpful.